# React-Native: Background app refresh while app closed

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

I need to update app's database every 30 or 60 minutes. After lots of search i've found this module :

https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch

As it says in its page:

> iOS Background Fetch is basically an API which wakes up your app about
>   every 15 minutes (during the user's prime-time hours) and provides
>   your app exactly 30s of background running-time. This plugin will
>   execute your provided callbackFn whenever a background-fetch event
>   occurs. There is no way to increase the rate which a fetch-event
>   occurs and this plugin sets the rate to the most frequent possible
>   value of UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum -- iOS determines
>   the rate automatically based upon device usage and time-of-day (ie:
>   fetch-rate is about ~15min during prime-time hours; less frequently
>   when the user is presumed to be sleeping, at 3am for example).

What if i write some code in swift? I'm using sqlite in react native to store my data. if i write some code in swift which wakes up and check for new data, can i access the same database that i used to store my data in react native?

I'm using react-native-sqlite-storage to store my data in react native.

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the database you used to store in react native, if you run the background task under same app